# Json case parse problem between Flutter and Net Core WebApi

Tags: c#, json, flutter, .net-core, case

I'm having this issue for a while between flutter and dotnet API communication, as the title says, I'm sending a request from flutter app with camelCase objects to dotnet core 3.1 API, but the object is always null, unless I modify my flutter object to PascalCase, which I don't want to. Its working with web, insomnia and others API calls. Literally everything "non-mobile" works.

Anyone had this issue? this also happened to me with angular PWA project as well. I tried to forcefully make dotnet parse json as camelcase or without a case at all, and nothing. It seems that if I send/receive from a non-mobile source the API doesn't care the case my object is, but if comes from mobile, it wont work unless its pascal case.

it may have nothing to do with casing at all, I'm assuming that's the problem because like I said, if the flutter object is on pascal everything works fine, the object passes through json parsing on the API call and my data is there. But if its not on pascal, object is always null, unless I change my objects inside dotnet to lowercase, again, I don't have to do this on any other web/api project that uses my webapi;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem wasnt the dotnet API, but the front-end side. The guy who's devloping angular PWA and Flutter app forgot to map the objects, he was sending the requests without map. It seems like a basic stuff, but it literally went for months like that. I'll leave this as right anwser here so that no one can suffer with this simple problem.